# Spring resttemplate 2 way ssl using spring boot

Tags: spring, ssl, httpclient, resttemplate

I'm consuming a RESTful Web Service using Spring Boot and restTemplate. The service is secured with 2 way ssl. So fare I have made this code to configure the connection. The code works but what I'm looking for is the best way to implement 2 way SSL with springs restTemplate and httpClient or another alternative using Spring Boot

```
@Configuration()
public class RestClientConfig {
   private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RestClientConfig.class);
   @Bean()
   @Qualifier("SSLRestOperations")
       public RestOperations restOperations(ClientHttpRequestFactory clientHttpRequestFactory) throws Exception {
       RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(clientHttpRequestFactory);    
       return restTemplate;
   }

   @Bean
   public ClientHttpRequestFactory clientHttpRequestFactory(HttpClient httpClient) {
       HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient);
      // timeout
      requestFactory.setReadTimeout(60 * 1000);
      requestFactory.setConnectTimeout(60 * 1000);
      return requestFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public HttpClient httpClient(@Value("${keystore.file}") Resource file, @Value("${keystore.pass}") Password password) throws Exception {
        String keystorePassword = password.getDescrambled();

        KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        TrustManagerFactory tmf =TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());

        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());

        InputStream instream = file.getInputStream();
        InputStream instreamKey = file.getInputStream();
        try {
            keyStore.load(instreamKey, keystorePassword.toCharArray());
            trustStore.load(instream, keystorePassword.toCharArray());

            kmf.init(keyStore, keystorePassword.toCharArray());
            tmf.init(trustStore);

        } finally {
            instream.close();
          instreamKey.close();
   }    

   SSLContext sslcontext = SSLContexts.custom().loadTrustMaterial(trustStore, new TrustSelfSignedStrategy())
    .loadKeyMaterial(trustStore, keystorePassword.toCharArray()).build();

   SSLSocketFactory socketFactory = sslcontext.getSocketFactory();
   SSLSocket socket = (SSLSocket) socketFactory.createSocket();

   SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslsf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslcontext, new String[] { "TLSv1.2" }, null, new NoopHostnameVerifier());

return HttpClients.custom().setSSLHostnameVerifier(new NoopHostnameVerifier()) // HostnameVerifier NoopHostnameVerifier
    .setSSLSocketFactory(sslsf)
    .build();
}
```

Comment: interesting link: http://www.robinhowlett.com/blog/2016/01/05/everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know-about-ssl-but-were-afraid-to-ask/#two-way-spring-boot

Comment: another interesting link: https://github.com/viniciusccarvalho/boot-two-way-ssl-example

Comment: Any success with this?